# Angular Js not being parsed by laravel 5- php

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

I have a blade view in laravel 5 along with my angular code as below

```
<li ng-if="data != null" class="item" style="height: 120px;"  data-ng-repeat="page in data | filter:searchDefaultTerm">
  <div style="margin: 5px;">
     <a href="<% page.guid %>"><span class="fa fa-eye pull-right"></span></a>
     <a href="{{ url('/administrator/page/edit/'.'<% page.id %>')}}" ><i class="fa  fa-pencil pull-right"></i></a>
     <a class="trashButton" href="{{ url('/administrator/page/delete/'.'<% page.id %>') }}" style="cursor: pointer;"><i class="fa fa-trash-o pull-right"><  /i></a>
  </div>
   <img class="pull-left product-img" style="margin: 5px;" height="100" width="100" src="<% page.image %>">
   <a class="product-title "><% page.title %></a><br/>
     <em style="margin: 5px;">Menu Title:</em> <a  class="product-title "><% page.menuTitle %></a><br/>             
     <em style="margin: 5px;">Added Date:</em> <a  class="product-title "><% page.addedDate %></a><br/>
     <em style="margin: 5px;">Updated Date:</em> <a  class="product-title "><% page.updateDate %></a>
</li>
```

Everything was woking fine in the angular development server but as soon as I moved it to wamp server I am getting the following error

> Use of undefined constant page - assumed 'page'

This is my angular code defining new start and end symbol for angular I dont have error with in my console caused due to angular

```
/*
* Angular App
*/
var app = angular.module('customApp',[],function($interpolateProvider){
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
});
```

I have also tried this

```
var app = angular.module('customApp', []);

app.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
});
```

This is the screenshot of error I have received [image]

Comment: Look [here](https://scotch.io/quick-tips/quick-tip-using-laravel-blade-with-angularjs)

Comment: i have already done what it said using Angular’s $interpolateProvider but still having some problem@SulthanAllaudeen

Comment: You made all config as like said [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29949833/3282633) ?\

Comment: i did so still not woking @SulthanAllaudeen

Comment: Whao ! After fresh installation or laravel-5 here's the solution that i have posted in the answer .. And it helped in my project as well. Thanks for your question +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

After a fresh installation of laravel-5. Here's the solution to you

Here's the `welcome.blade.php`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Laravel</title>

        <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        {!! HTML::style('public/css/app.css') !!} 
        {!! HTML::script('public/js/angular.min.js'); !!}
    </head>
    <body>
    @include('angular-stuff'); <!-- app/views/angular-stuff.php -->     
    </body>
</html>
```

There have a angular-stuff.php file in your `app/views` folder

Inside your `angular-stuff.php` have the below code

```
<div ng-app="">
    <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
    <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
</div>
```

Then it should work without any other configuration.

**Note :**  Your file your be `angular-stuff.php` not `angular-stuff.blade.php`